# Incorrect redirect from ASP.NET MVC application under URL Rewrite

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting, arr

I have the next configuration of websites in the IIS:

- `http://main.domain.com` website (ASP.NET MVC 5 app, website binded to the specified host, port 80)
- default website binded to :80 with ARR/URL Rewrite module enabled

A wildcard binding `*.domain.com` is specified in DNS settings.

The desired behavior is to have `http://main.domain.com` as an entry point and a set of dynamic user-subdomains like `http://user1.domain.com`, `http://user2.domain.com`, etc.

Now this behavior is simulated using links like `http://main.domain.com/user/user1`

I have set up the URL Rewrite rule for `main.domain.com` in the way like this:

```
<rule name="user-redirection" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^.*$" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^([\w\d-]+)\.domain\.com$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="http://main.domain.com/user/{C:1}/{R:0}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

Everything is ok here - I can see that `http://user1.domain.com` works just like `http://main.domain.com/user/user1` as it worked earlier.

Then I try to re-implement a logic of checking the existance of specified user in the database. For instance, when **user47** doesn't exist - opening of the `http://main.domain.com/user/user47` link leads to redirection to the `http://main.domain.com` entry point.

In the code-side it is done by adding custom filter attribute to the controller action that implements the needed conditional redirect. I have the next code:

```
public class UserController : Controller {
    [CustomRedirectBehavior]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       ...
    }
}

public class CustomRedirectBehaviorAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        ...

        if (redirectingCondition) {
          filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("http://main.domain.com");
        }
    }
}
```

And here.... I get a cyclic redirection error in the browser! To be certain - I have double-checked this behavior:

1. When I open `http://main.domain.com/user/user47` I'm properly redirected to `http://main.domain.com`
2. When I open `http://user47.domain.com/` I get a cyclic redirection error.

Then in order to investigate the problem I've modified redirect callback to:

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("http://someotherdomain.com/some/other/path");
```

And.... I can see that:

1. When I open `http://main.domain.com/user/user47` I'm properly redirected to `http://someotherdomain.com/some/other/path`
2. When I open `http://user47.domain.com/` I'm redirected to `http://user47.domain.com/some/other/path` !!! (And yes, that's not a typo and I've also double-checked this behavior)

So. I need an idea on how to pass through this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... Finally I got the answer.

The problem was coming from the **Application Request Routing (ARR)** module being installed in order to make rewriting work with custom subdomains.

The **Reverse rewrite host in response headers** option was set to true by default after enabling proxy in the **Server Proxy Settings** area. Disabling this setting makes redirect working correctly under subdomain-based rewriting.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to reproduce your case and it seems you are really getting a redirecting loop. So I added a negative lookahead group (`(?!main)`) into the pattern and it works for me. This is how my web.config looks:

```
<rule name="user-redirection" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^.*$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!main)([\w\d-]+)\.domain\.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://main.domain.com/user/{C:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

In order to investigate your problem I've tried:

1. Disable browser cache. If your browser using cache it might you will not see every change of the rule you made.
2. Change the type of action to be "Redirect" instead of "Rewrite" and watching what's going on in the "Network" tab in the "Developer tools (F12)".
   e.g. `<action type="Redirect" ...`

Comment: Great answer. Need some time to check if it helps. Do you have any idea, why am I getting `http://user47.domain.com/some/other/path` as a destination URL in last specified case?

Comment: I've tried several times and it works for me.
You can see what actually RedirectResult is doing for you [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/db728cd3866ed5054367fd479259441d4a72cef4/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/ActionResults/RedirectResult.cs).
Also you can try to do it manually using [System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://domain.com")](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9dwyts4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Which version of asp.net mvc you are using?
Do you have any other redirects/rewrites?
Do you have any piece of code which clears "redirect" headers from the response?

Comment: thanks for your great help. I've just found the answer an posted it below.